# Renaming artifacts to last GitHub commit in Artifactory deployment using Git macro

Tags: git, github, teamcity, cicd

I´m currently trying to establish a way to deploy artefacts from our buildserver to artifactory. Therefore I want to rename the file to the Last commit done in Github.

I tried to use the git macro to get the last tag:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

By setting this command as a configuration parameter. So I tried to use a configuration parameter named:

```
output
```

with the value of the command:

```
%git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

and use it as an upload spec

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "*.bin",
      "target": "Path_X/%output%/",
      "props": "status=ready"
    }
  ]
}
```

But then its not using it as a command, rather using it as normal characters.